# why do i get this-- > importError: No module named backend.libusb10

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

my code is to get all details about the device inserted in USB port.
However, when i run the program i get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named backend.libusb10
```

Can someone please explain?
I have checked my site-packages folder and i have backend.
thanks, in advance :)

here is my code

```
import usb.core
import usb.util
import usb

# find our device
dev = usb.core.find(find_all=True)
busses = usb.busses()
# was it found?
if dev is None:
    raise ValueError('Device not found')

for bus in busses:
    devices = bus.devices
    for dev in devices:
        try:
            _name = usb.util.get_string(dev.dev, 19, 1)
        except:
            continue
        dev.set_configuration()
        cfg = dev.get_active_configuration()
        interface_number = cfg[(0,0)].bInterfaceNumber
        alternate_settting = usb.control.get_interface(interface_number)
        print "Device name:",_name
        print "Device:", dev.filename
        print "  idVendor:",hex(dev.idVendor)
        print "  idProduct:",hex(dev.idProduct)
        for config in dev.configurations:
            print "  Configuration:", config.value
            print "    Total length:", config.totalLength 
            print "    selfPowered:", config.selfPowered
            print "    remoteWakeup:", config.remoteWakeup
            print "    maxPower:", config.maxPower
        print
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Yamit Kashyap/Desktop/ID_USB", line 6, in <module>
    dev = usb.core.find(find_all=True)
  File "Z:\Work\Python\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 836, in find
    import usb.backend.libusb10 as libusb10
ImportError: No module named backend.libusb10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe its because you are working on windows. Try switching to ubuntu.
Tried your code on my machine, works like a charm.

Steps:

1. Download pyusb-1.0.0a3.zip (or whichever version is there) from http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyusb/
2. Extract the zip file, go inside that folder from terminal and type 
   "python setup.py install"
3. Continue with what you were doing.